# Why don't static queries work in Storybook?

Tags: gatsby, storybook, prismic.io

### Description

I'm getting "Loading (StaticQuery)" in Storybook for any component that uses `StaticQuery` and "The result of this StaticQuery could not be fetched." in Storybook for any component that uses `useStaticQuery`. Everything seems to work fine locally and when built, but in Storybook I am getting this:

Minimal reproduction: https://github.com/mrseanbaines/gatsby-storybook-static-query

#### Steps to reproduce

1. Clone the repo (`git@github.com:mrseanbaines/gatsby-storybook-static-query.git`)
2. Run Storybook (`yarn storybook`)

#### Expected result

The components should render

#### Actual result

I get errors instead

#### Environment

Using `gatsby-source-prismic-graphql` to source data. Also happens with `@prismicio/gatsby-source-prismic-graphql`.

```sh
  System:
    OS: macOS 10.15.6
    CPU: (8) x64 Intel(R) Core(TM) i5-8279U CPU @ 2.40GHz
    Shell: 5.7.1 - /bin/zsh
  Binaries:
    Node: 12.17.0 - ~/.nvm/versions/node/v12.17.0/bin/node
    Yarn: 1.22.4 - ~/.yarn/bin/yarn
    npm: 6.14.4 - ~/.nvm/versions/node/v12.17.0/bin/npm
  Languages:
    Python: 2.7.16 - /usr/bin/python
  Browsers:
    Chrome: 84.0.4147.125
    Firefox: 79.0
    Safari: 13.1.2
  npmPackages:
    gatsby: 2.24.43 => 2.24.43 
    gatsby-source-prismic-graphql: 3.6.2 => 3.6.2
```

Comment: did you find a solution to this?

Answer (score 0):

In the .storybook folder in your project edit the main.js as follows.

```
module.exports = {
  "stories": [
    //your stories
    "../src/**/*.stories.mdx",
    "../src/**/*.stories.@(js|jsx|ts|tsx)"
  ],
  "addons": [
    //your addons
    "@storybook/addon-links",
    "@storybook/addon-essentials",
    "storybook-css-modules-preset"
  ],
 // This config to exlude gatsby node modules saved me.
  webpackFinal: async config => {
    // Transpile Gatsby module because Gatsby includes un-transpiled ES6 code.
    config.module.rules[0].exclude = [/node_modules\/(?!(gatsby)\/)/]
    return config;
  }
}
```

Reference https://www.gatsbyjs.com/docs/how-to/testing/visual-testing-with-storybook/

This way any imports from gatsby will not break storybook